# What is the easiest way to access nodes within known types using UA-.NETStandard?

Tags: opc-ua

Summary

I am working on a simple proof of concept for a visualization in Blazor.

I have a created a demo server representing an equipment that exposes a folder with two instances of a "MeasurementType". The types are generated using the ModelCompiler. "Output" is of type "AnalogUnitRangeType"

Address space:

```
+ Root
    + Objects
        + Equipment
            + Supply
                + Pressure of MeasurementType
                + Humidity of MeasurementType
```

MeasurementType:

```
+ Measurement
    + Output of AnalogUnitRangeType (double)
        + EURange
        + EngineeringUnits
```

I am using Blazor to create the UI and the Opc Foundation Nuget package to browse the server to dynamically generate a user interface. In this case that will be two components representing "Pressure" and "Humidity"

Question:

When browsing a server and finding known self-defined types like MeasurementType. What is the easiest way to access the child nodes?

I am browsing all nodes and checking if they are measurementTypes like this:

```
if (node.TypeDefinitionId.Identifier.ToString() == 
ObjectTypeIds.MeasurementType.Identifier.ToString())
```

When I find the types I keep browsing the references and matching on displayName to find the variables I need. Since I know the type there is probably an easier way.

As an example, I was hoping that it might be possible to do something similar to this?

```
if(node is MeasurementState)
{
    var measurementNode = node as MeasurementState;
}
```

I have looked through the samples, but must admit I find it a bit overwhelmimg. If you have any good resources that explains the opcfoundation sdk that would also be highly appreciated.